# Retrieving RSSI value of connected Wireless device

Tags: c#, wifi, rssi

I want to develop an application which can list all the connected devices to my wifi network and their RSSI values.Could some one tell me how to approach this.Any sample codes would be of help and preferabbly in c sharp.Thanks.

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
...

List<String> _ComputerNames = new List<String>();
String _ComputerSchema = "Computer";
DirectoryEntry _WinNTDirectoryEntries = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT:");
foreach (DirectoryEntry _AvailDomains in _WinNTDirectoryEntries.Children)
{
    foreach (DirectoryEntry _PCNameEntry in _AvailDomains.Children)
    {
        if (_PCNameEntry.SchemaClassName.ToLower().Contains(_ComputerSchema.ToLower()))
        {
            _ComputerNames.Add(_PCNameEntry.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

This code lists the connected devices but how to get the RSSI value of these devices.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. Search in google ...

Comment: I have edited the question providing sample code which lists the connected devices.I am not able to figure out how to get the rssi values.Could you please provide some information regarding this.Thanks. @mybirthname

Comment: I have edited the question providing sample code which lists the connected devices.I am not able to figure out how to get the rssi values.Could you please provide some information regarding this.Thanks. @mybirthname